How to Refresh a DataTable After Deleting an Item Without Reloading the Page in Vue.js?
I am working on a Vue.js application with a settings/roles page. In this page, I have a DataTable component, and I want to delete an item using a dropdown menu option. After deleting the item, I would like to refresh the DataTable without reloading the page.
I have added the shadcn-vue row actions to our table, and use a <Dropdown /> component for this, as discuss here.
<DataTable :data="role" :columns="roleColumn" />
DataTableRowActions component:
<script setup lang="ts">
import type { Row } from '@tanstack/vue-table'
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button'
import { DotsHorizontalIcon } from '@radix-icons/vue'
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { roleDtoSchema, type RoleDto } from '@/data/schema'
import { deleteRole } from '@/api/permission'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

import { ref } from 'vue'
const router = useRouter()

interface DataTableRowActionsProps {
  row: Row<RoleDto>
}
const props = defineProps<DataTableRowActionsProps>()
const role = computed(() => roleDtoSchema.parse(props.row.original))
const showDeleteDialog = ref(false)

const handleDeleteRole = async () => {
  try {
    await deleteRole(role.value.id)
    showDeleteDialog.value = false
  } catch (error: any) {
  } finally {
  }
}
</script>
<template>
  <!-- Dropdown Menu -->
  <DropdownMenu>
    <DropdownMenuTrigger as-child>
      <Button variant="ghost" class="flex h-8 w-8 p-0 data-[state=open]:bg-muted">
        <DotsHorizontalIcon class="h-4 w-4" />
        <span class="sr-only">Open menu</span>
      </Button>
    </DropdownMenuTrigger>
    <DropdownMenuContent align="end" class="w-[160px]">
      {{ role }}
      <DropdownMenuItem @click="$router.push(`/settings/roles/edit/${role.id}`)">Update Role</DropdownMenuItem>
      <DropdownMenuSeparator />
      <DropdownMenuItem class="text-red-600" @select="showDeleteDialog = true">
        Delete
        <DropdownMenuShortcut>⌘⌫</DropdownMenuShortcut>
      </DropdownMenuItem>
    </DropdownMenuContent>
  </DropdownMenu>
  <AlertDialog v-model:open="showDeleteDialog">
    <AlertDialogContent>
      <AlertDialogHeader>
        <AlertDialogTitle>Are you absolutely sure?</AlertDialogTitle>
        <AlertDialogDescription>
          This action cannot be undone. This role will no longer be
          accessible.
        </AlertDialogDescription>
      </AlertDialogHeader>
      <AlertDialogFooter>
        <AlertDialogCancel>Cancel</AlertDialogCancel>
        <Button variant="destructive" @click="handleDeleteRole">
          Delete
        </Button>
      </AlertDialogFooter>
    </AlertDialogContent>
  </AlertDialog>
</template>


handleDeleteRole
const handleDeleteRole = async () => {
    await deleteRole(role.value.id)
    showDeleteDialog.value = false
    router.replace('/settings/roles'); 
}

After the delete operation I want to avoid a full page reload and instead update the DataTable data directly.
How can I effectively refresh the DataTable after deleting an item without refreshing the entire page? Is there a common practice for handling such scenarios in Vue.js?
To get the role data i have used unplugin-vue-router dataloader.
<script lang="ts">
import { getRoles } from '@/api/usergroups';
import { defineBasicLoader } from 'unplugin-vue-router/data-loaders/basic'


export const useRoleData = defineBasicLoader('roles', async () => {
  return getRoles()
})


</script>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { roleColumn } from '@/components/roles/column'
const {
  data: role, // the data returned by the loader
} = useRoleData()

</script>
<template>
   <DataTable :data="role" :columns="roleColumn" />
</template>

role column
import type { ColumnDef } from '@tanstack/vue-table'
import type { RoleDto } from '@/data/schema'
import { h } from 'vue'

import DataTableColumnHeader from '@/components/ui/data-table-column.vue' // Adjust the path as needed
import DataTableRowActions  from "@/components/roles/role-row-action.vue";

export const roleColumn: ColumnDef<RoleDto>[] = [
  {
    accessorKey: 'name',
    header: ({ column }) => h(DataTableColumnHeader, { column, title: 'Role Name' })
  },
  {
    id: 'actions',
    header: ({ column }) => h(DataTableColumnHeader, { column, title: 'Action' }),

    cell: ({ row }) => h(DataTableRowActions, { row }),
  },
]


Why did you make a table with a construction from columns, and not from rows? All you had to do was pass the emit('delete', row.id). And in the parent component, where you store the rawTable reactive data, delete the row by index.
In your case, you need to delete data from the roleColumn, and you will have to go through all the columns and remove the row whose ID you pass. Since the data is reactive, there will be no need to refresh the page, and everything will be updated immediately.

Whole point of Vue is to update data on the page without refreshing the page. All the data that needs to be refreshed should go through reactivity state controllers 'ref' and 'reactive'. You should try to understand those two concepts better - it is described in the docs https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html
In your Datatable <DataTable :data="role" :columns="roleColumn" /> "role" should be a reactive object and it should be updated properly triggering reactivity. Once you properly set this variable, DataTable will be automatically refreshed the moment any data in the "role" variable would change, and you will not need to trigger anything.
There is really no way around it - you need to understand how to make variables reactive in Vue, otherwise, there is no point using Vue at all. It's the most important concept in Vue.
